# What does Puppet indicate with notice "altered - with untracked files"

Tags: puppet, configuration-management

I receive the following notice from a `puppet agent -t` run that does (or at least should) not effect any changes:

```
Info: Applying configuration version '<id> - altered - with untracked files'
```

What is the meaning of the clause `altered - with untracked files`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the configuration version is just epoch, so your configuration version will look something like

```
Info: Applying configuration version '1369841032'
```

However, it's nicer to be able to tie in what version of your code is being used by Puppet, especially if it's in version control. So you can specify a script to create a configuration version in the `environment.conf` file:

Something simple like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/git --git-dir $1/$2/.git rev-parse HEAD
```

Will give you a much nicer git ref instead:

```
Info: Applying configuration version 'a6a415b9d4da22b534b57aeca575dc49d834fccb'
```

So someone can go look that git reference up in your Git repo to figure out what code is being used.

(Docs [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/config_file_environment.html#configversion))

So what's happened here is that the script has gone wrong in some way, and instead of giving a nice git commit, it's just exited that string...

Check the `configversion` setting in your `environment.conf`, find out what script is being used and try and debug why it's giving that string instead.

Comment: Thx, I'll investigate along these lines.